# Include arrays with the same name from different files in PHP?

Tags: php, include

I am trying to figure out how I can include arrays that have the same name into my PHP file from two different files .

I know it's simple, but I can't seem to find the right search to get me to the solution.

I've been trying to reference the arrays such as `function_call(menu_config.$config)` but that just isn't working.

Comment: I am sure I have seen this question once already today

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming both files have a `$config` array.  If you want one resulting array:

```
include('file1.php');
$new = $config;

include('file2.php');
$new = array_merge($new, $config);
```

Or even two new arrays:

```
include('file1.php');
$config_1 = $config;

include('file2.php');
$config_2 = $config;
```

Another option would be a function:

```
function get_config($file) {
    include($file);
    return $config;
}

$config_1 = get_config('file1.php');
```

Comment: Thats rather cute, simple, and a bit embaracing for the questioner

Comment: This is working, but does this actually make sense? At least a hint should be added, that such global variables in included files are, well, questionable.

Comment: I think its delicious

Comment: i think i'll go with that middle one.  I think for where i'm at it's exactly what i'm looking for, thanks!  Also, its embarrassing ;)

Comment: It decided i wanted to be able to load files dynamically based on information gathered during runtime, so i went with the function call, and it works great.  Thanks Abra!